# Programatically Prioritise Disk I/O in Win7

Tags: .net, process, io

From the [website](http://bitsum.com/prolasso.php) of "Process Lasso", they claim:

> Automatically temporarily lower the CPU priority class and/or I/O
>   priority of monopolizing process(es)

Does anyone know how to specify the I/O Priority for a specific process/thread? To clarify the problem, I run Fluid Simulations on my machine using RealFlow which plays nicely with the CPU but throws around 20GB-sized files quite frequently. This results in a huge disk queue and other, lightweight apps hang.

I'd like to write a simple wrapper that launches RealFlow, drops the I/O priority and exits - something as simple as...

```
Sub Main()
    ...
    Dim RealFlowProcess = Process.Start("RealFlow.exe", "Args")
    RealFlowProcess.??? = ???
    ...
End Sub
```

I'd prefer a pure .Net solution but frankly anything that runs on a dev's box without too much overhead would be acceptable (Powershell/C++/etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a discussion about that topic that contains the answer and a lot of background info: https://superuser.com/questions/136021/how-to-change-i-o-priority-of-a-process-or-thread-in-win7